# Visual Studio 2012 "the project file has been moved, renamed, or is not on your computer"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'd been working on a visual studio project, and decided to rename it. After a little bit of renaming, everything was under the new name. I tried to open the project in Visual Studio, and the load failed, saying the project file had been moved, renamed, or deleted. I can edit the project via the C# project file among the other class files, but no matter how I try to rename files to change it back, the load still fails.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Which are you editing and which are you opening?  The .csproj file or the .sln file, or both?

Comment: Should be a simple remove the project from the solution, and then add an existing project back (selecting the renamed `csproj`).  This makes me thing you renamed the folder that the project sat in?

Comment: I had been editing the `.sln` until the rename, and then could only edit via `csproj`. I checked the path to the project, renamed the files to fit it, and then the `.sln` started working again. Thanks for the help! @GrantWinney

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but with VS 2019. I changed the name of the project and then got the same error. I fixed it by editing the .sln file because when I changed the name of the project one line didn't change. It was like this:

oldnamefolder\newnameproject.csproj

I changed it

newnamefolder\newnameproject.csproj